# Storing only the text of a html list item in a javascript array and not the image src as well

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, text

In HTML I have an unordered list with items like

```
<ul id="sortable">
<li class="ui-state-default"><img src="images/john.jpg">John</li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><img src="images/lisa.jpg">Lisa</li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><img src="images/bill.jpg">Bill</li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><img src="images/sara.jpg">Sara</li>
</ul>
```

I want to store the names of a selected item in an array and the selection is working fine, the problem is that its also storing the img src as well as the name.

This is my code used to populate the array:

```
var dataArr = [];
$("#sortable li").each(function(idx, elem) {
    dataArr[idx] = $(elem).html();
});
```

If I were then to output dataArr[0] I would get a return string of "< img src="images/ john.jpg ">John" when I obviously just want "John".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: `dataArr[idx] = $(elem).text();`
`.text()` will give you only textual children of the node

Answer (score 2):

Use `text()` instead of `html()`:

```
dataArr[idx] = $(elem).text();
```

Or, to be a little cheaper and avoid the cost of wrapping in a jQuery object each iteration:

```
dataArr[idx] = elem.textContent || elem.innerText;
```

References:

- [`text()`](http://api.jQuery.com/text/).

Answer (score 2):

```
    var dataArr = [];
  $("#sortable li").each(function(idx, elem) {    
     dataArr[idx]   = $(elem).text();
    });
```

Comment: But he wants the text, such as 'John,' not the `src`.

Comment: sorry i thought that he needs image name

Comment: It's not a problem, I wasn't going to down-vote, but thought I'd try and save you from others that might. =)